# superscipt and subscript characters in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm creating a database using SQLite 3. Many of my fields are gonna need superscripts and subscripts, e.g. h20, etc. What do I need to do to be able to specify a subscript or superscript? Do I need to use unicode to specify the special character? If so, will I have to specify a different data type for the entire column? Right now, I'm using "text" bc thats what's going in there...

Any examples demonstrating how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqlite3 can handle UTF-8 and UTF-16 values, and the TEXT column type should work fine. You didn't mention which language you're using, but in Python, for example, you can pass `unicode` params directly:

```
import os
import sqlite3

os.unlink('unicode.db')
conn = sqlite3.connect('unicode.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE uc (value TEXT)")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO uc VALUES (?)", (u'h\u2082o',))
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM uc")
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print row[0]
```

Output:

```
h₂o
```